# Defining jquery when it's undefined

Tags: jquery

When the error `$(document).ready(function(){ is undefined`, this is because the jquery library is not on the page for my situation, but this error occurs since I have a small jquery plug-in on my pages to resolve an issue when jquery the library is present during a particular time of the user's session.

Besides placing the jquery library on the page when this particular error occurs, what is the solution to simply check if jquery is present or so the error does not occur on the page overall?

Comment: There should be a jQuery plugin for this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Only do anything if jQuery isn't defined
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {

} else { // jQuery was already loaded   
   // Run your jQuery Code
};
```

Comment: i saw a couple others share this, but i used yours first. this worked great, because i was then able to wrap my plug-in within the else statement. thank you for the solution!

Comment: @Evan: Just an FYI- apsillers posted this same answer first and with a lot more detail.

Comment: no need for the wrap, you could have just prefixed your plugin with `window.jQuery && ` per my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you don't want to use jQuery universally for some reason, you can safely check if jQuery is not loaded by:

```js
if(window.jQuery == undefined)
```

since accessing undefined properties of the global `window` object doesn't raise an error, whereas using an undeclared variable name does. (Note this assumes an unaltered `undefined`; you can add in `var undefined;` before this line if you can't make that assumption.)

Or simply:

```js
if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
```

since `typeof` doesn't complain about undeclared variable names. (Specifically, according to [the ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3), `typeof` returns the string `"undefined"` when `IsUnresolvableReference` returns `true` for the given identifier.)

Answer (score 3):

try

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
}
```

[`Reference`](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html)

you can also check [if particular jQuery plugin is loaded or not.](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/03/check-if-jquery-plugin-is-loaded.html)

Answer (score 2):

Following code will register the jQuery library when it is not registered.

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean short-circuit operators can help:

```
window.jQuery && (function($) {

     $.fn.myPlugin = ...

})(jQuery);
```

which will only create the plug in if jQuery exists.

Comment: But, the $ may be something other than jQuery.

Comment: It may, but if it is, the `$(document)` line will fail anyway.

Comment: Which is exactly what he's trying to avoid :)

Comment: almost every answer here is equivalent, they're just checking for the presence of jQuery (whether using `$` or `jQuery`).  He asked about jQuery being `undefined`, not some other package using `$`.

Comment: @Alnintak the `$` is not a synonym for jQuery, other answers refer to `jQuery` literally.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I changed that.  However, if jQuery is loaded then (by default) `$` _is_ a synonym for `jQuery`.

Comment: @Alnitak absolutely not. `$` can be anything

Comment: @DavidFregoli yes, I said _by default_.